# How do I update an iframe from another iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, getelementbyid

I have an iframe with LOGIN and REGISTER buttons, the login button opens the login page in another iframe, and after submitting the login data the second iframe is refreshed.

However, I would like to be able to also update the first iframe to change my LOGIN button to my LOGOUT button.

$_SESSION['userlevel'] does have a value, and my loginmenu.php works fine to reflect the correct button when the whole page is refreshed with F5

here is part of my index page which loads the code for my LOGIN and REGISTER buttons ...

```
   <div class="login">
    <iframe class="iframemain" name="iframe-login" id="loginmenu" src="loginmenu.php"></iframe>
   </div>
```

here is my loginmenu.php ...

```
<?php session_start();?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="0000001.css" type="text/css" />
<title> </title>
</head>

<body class="login">
<?php
$userlevel=$_SESSION['userlevel'];

if ($userlevel=="") 
{
 ?><a href="login.php" target="iframemain"><img id="loginImg" src="gfx/btn.menulogin.png"/></a><img src="gfx/spacer.png" width="2px"/><a href="register.php" target="iframe-body"><img src="gfx/btn.menuregister.png"/></a><?php
}

if ($userlevel<>"") 
{
 ?><a href="logout.php" target="iframemain"><img src="gfx/btn.menulogout.png"/></a><img src="gfx/spacer.png" width="2px"/><a href="register.php" target="iframe-body"><img src="gfx/btn.menuregister.png"/></a><?php
}

?>

</body>

</html>
```

after validating the username and password ($form is actually "valid") ... here is my failing attempt to update my loginmenu.php ...

```
<?php

(validing code here)

if($form=="valid")
 {
  ?>
  <script>
  element=document.getElementById('loginmenu')
  element.src="loginmenu.php";
  </script>
  <?php
 }

(other php functions here)

?>
```

i have also tried this to see if the image will change, but it also fails

```
if($form=="valid")
 {
  ?>
  <script>
  element=document.getElementById('loginImg')
  element.src="gfx/btn.menulogout.png";
  </script>
  <?php
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give names to your iframes, then you can refer the window objects in iframes from anywhere like so:

```
var windowInIframe = top.frame_name;
```

If you use this method, you need to set `window.location.href` instead of `src` to load a new page to an iframe.

Comment: it has a name "iframe-login" - should i use getElementByName instead ?  - please note, i have only been learning css and php for 2 weeks and javascript for one day, so be gentle.  also can you explain why my codes do not work even though they are identifying specific IDs?

Comment: No, in name="IframeA" you can get an element in name="IframeB" by referring it like `top.IframeB.document.getElementById('the_id')`. `top` is a property of `window`, an it refers to the top-most window in the browser's viewport, i.e. the window containing your `iframe` elements.

Comment: i have tried this, but it still fails ...
element=top.iframe-login.document.getElementById('loginmenu')
element.src="loginmenu.php";

Comment: excellent, thank you - i had to rename the iframe to iframe_login :) - the hyphen seemed to be an issue

Comment: That's my bad, I didn't look you DTD properly : ). Anyway, you also may want to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) an answer, which best works for you.

Comment: i have finall settled on ... 
top.iframe_login.document.getElementById('loginImg').src="gfx/btn.menulogout.png";   
top.iframe_login.document.getElementById('loginLink').href="logout.php";   
this updates the one image and it's link instead of the whole iframe, which causes the REGISTRATION button to disappear and reappear and looks a little untidy - but i have learned some very valuable info today - thank you again

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
var links = [
    'javascript:\'<button onclick="parent.twonav(1)">Change 2nd frame</button>\'',
    'javascript:\'Hello\''
];
var one, two;
window.onload=function() {
  one = document.getElementById('frameone');
  two = document.getElementById('frametwo');
}  

function onenav(idx) {
    one.src=links[idx];
}  

function twonav(idx) {
    two.src=links[idx];
}
```

Refer this link http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/WH4ns/

Comment: yes, i have seen this on my attempt to find a solution, but i want to avoid having to press a button - everything i have found, and the website i am learning from, tends to rely on a button press !!